# C# Serialization / Deserialization: Same object different project

Tags: c#, serialization

Basic example:

```
Person person = new Person("Bob",50);
BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, person);

Byte[] data = memoryStream.ToArray();

MemoryStream received = new MemoryStream(data,false);

object obj = binaryFormatter.Deserialize(received);

if (obj is Person)
{
    Person des = obj as Person;

    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", des.Name, des.Age);
}
```

The problem is that I cannot rebuild the byte stream if I make the same class (names, fields) in a different project.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: What is the reason behind using MemoryStream here ? What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: As your answer says, Binary serialization contains detailed type information (not just full namespace, but version as well), and you can't deserialize to another type (even though it looks the same, if its in a different assembly, its a different type). The only solution is to move it to an assembly that can be referenced by both projects or to use a different form of serialization. Even worse, if you modify the assembly that contains it, it may break your serialized objects.

Answer (score 2):

Put the shared code in a third project, then reference that shared project in both your current projects.

Now they both have access to the class, but not to anything you don't want shared.

Is there a particular reason you're using .net Binary Serialization?

The more modern approach would be to use a data format like JSON.

Specifically [JSON.Net](http://json.net/).

It's much more flexible, allowing you to deserialize to any class that "looks" the same, or to even use a dictionary or a dynamic object.

Here's another SO answer describing why the Binary Formatter isn't a great choice: [I hate to say it, but my first pointer here would be "don't do that"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205347/net-binary-formatter-deserialize-an-object-whose-definition-has-changed-a-lot)